# getenv returns false if a variable is not set: how to differentiate with "false" values?

Tags: php, environment-variables

How do I differentiate between "the environment variable is not set" and "the environment variable equals `false`" if `getenv` returns `false` in both cases?

If I'm not clear enough, here is the PHP documentation for `getenv`:

> Returns the value of the environment variable varname, or FALSE if the environment variable varname does not exist.

Comment: use binary representation of booleans?

Comment: Is it possible to set an environment variable as a Boolean? Isn't it a string or a numeric?

Comment: @MarkBaker very good point, to be honest I don't know